# Retrieve data of last month uploads

Tags: mysql, sql, function, select

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a database using MySQL. I would like to `SELECT` just the records that I uploaded in the last month and not the previous ones.
 This script has to be dynamic : I mean that on 1st of February it should retrieve data from 1st of January to 1st of February and so on.
My table structure is really simple : the upload date is stored in the column 'reg_date' that is a `TIMESTAMP` type.
Does anyone know how to do this in a single query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can all be done in a single SQL query using the CURDATE() and INTERVAL functions so no PHP date calculation is required.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `TABLE` 
WHERE `reg_date` BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND CURDATE()
```

Comment: This gives me an empty set. Do I need to change the type of TIMESTAMP formats? Currently is DD-MM-YYYY.

Comment: Dates of all types are stored as YYYY-MM-DD unless you did something very odd

Comment: Dates were stored as YYYY-MM-DD HH-MI-SS. I've just changed the type to YYYY-MM-DD but it's still giving me an empty set.

Comment: Do you have any data in the range 2017-03-03 to 2017-04-03

Comment: Of course I do. I'm not a newbie but this is getting me crazy.

Comment: Sorry but I had to ask, remember I cannot see what you are really doing and you didnt show any of your data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139795/discussion-between-hexadect-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: If this or @GurV version do not work then there is something amiss with your database or there is something you are not telling us

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the data like so:

```
select *
from your_table
where reg_date between date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month) and curdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this query:

```
select * from your_table_name where reg_date between '2017-03-01' and '2017-03-31';
```

Comment: I need to do this dynamically. For example, this script on 14th December must retrieve data from 14th November to 14th December.

Comment: you have to define that inside your php code. you have to define two variables which will hold the dates.